# Does Jena RDF/ model class support other RDF serialization model that RDF/XML

Tags: rdf, jena, rdfa, rdfs

I wanted to know whether Jena [RDF.Model Class](http://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/jena/com/hp/hpl/jena/rdf/model/Model.html) support particular  RDF serialization format or it converts any serialization formnat providing RDF data into Model.

Comment: I think you should take a look at [Jena I/O](http://jena.apache.org/documentation/io/iohowto.html)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is possible to serialize and parse Jena models in/from various formats (RDF/XML, N3, Turtle, N-Triples). See [jena.apache.org/documentation/io/index.html](http://jena.apache.org/documentation/io/index.html) for an overview, or the [I/O section of the tutorial](http://jena.apache.org/tutorials/rdf_api.html#ch-Writing%20RDF).